How to get device size in main function (without context) flutter
I`m trying to get the device size to choose if the device orientation will be landscapeLeft and landscapeRight, or any.
The problem is, the only way i found was using context, how can i get it in main function?
the getter window is deprecated
I tried to use getDeviceType from responsive_builder
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:flutter_modular/flutter_modular.dart';

import 'app/app_module.dart';
import 'app/app_widget.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // set orientation to landscape
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight],
  );

  // load environment variables
  await dotenv.load();

  runApp(
    ModularApp(
      module: AppModule(),
      child: const AppWidget(),
    ),
  );
}

if (getDeviceType(MediaQueryData.fromView(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).size) == DeviceScreenType.tablet) {
    await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight],
    );
}

